# IOS - How to force the view to landscape

Tags: ios, uiview, autorotate

I want to force my view to go for landscape, just when I call a method.

When my method runs I call:

```
[self shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
```

Method to autorotate

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation);
}
```

The problem is that the view don't force the rotation. Is possible to test it on the simulator, or just works in real device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight animated:YES];
```

Comment: I've one problem. The view that I created inside, is not set to landscape :S Now it should have 480 width and 320 height, right? But it doesn't :S

Comment: It sounds like you need to create a view with a relative size. So instead of creating a view with `initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)]`, try something like `initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height])`